Skeleton loader not showing when useFetch status is pending
I'm trying to implement an image gallery with a skeleton loader that should display while the images are loading. However, for some reason, the loader is not showing up even with throttling on. I understand that I should use the onload event to check if the images are loaded, but I want to verify that the skeleton loader works while the data is being fetched. If I set the condition to v-if="status !== 'pending'", I can see the skeleton. I tried adding a delay await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000)); before imgList.value = data.value.data;, but I still couldn't see the loader. Also, tried using <Suspense> to use a skeleton as a fallback, but it didn't work.
Reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-63w6mv?file=app%2Fpages%2Fgallery.vue
Template:
<div class="w-32 h-32 bg-white" v-if="status === 'pending'" />
<img
  class="w-full cursor-pointer rounded-lg object-cover shadow-2xl"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  :src="item.url"
  v-else
/>

Script:
const imgList = ref<Image[]>([]);

const { apiBase } = useRuntimeConfig().public;
const { data, status, error } = await useFetch<{ data: Image[] }>(
  `${apiBase}/get-images`,
  { lazy: true }
);
watchEffect(() => {
  if (status.value === 'success') {
    if (data.value) {
      // await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));
      imgList.value = data.value.data;
    }
    console.log(data.value.data);
  } else if (status.value === 'error') {
    console.error('Error loading images: ', error.value);
  }
});

I'm looking for a possible solution.

/get-images response is immediate, I guess at least because a sandbox uses a service worker, it's not a good starter to debug a skeleton,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-ecmqmn?file=app%2Fpages%2Fgallery.vue . And "await new Promise" delay doesn't matter because it doesn't affect "status"

@EstusFlask I have the same logic in my local project, but I use my data from postgres db instead of a dummy data in this repro and I still don't see the skeleton, even if I set immediate: false in useFetch

@EstusFlask If I log in my local project with the logs you provided in the link above, I see next: 1) ssr status: 0.11ms success 2) ssr (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] (the data) 3) status: 0.028076171875 ms success 4) (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] (the data). If I also log if (status.value === 'pending') { console.log('pending...'); } I don't see pending in the console at all...

Other states are seen only in client-side routing. When you refresh /gallery, it's served from server side, and because you use await useFetch, it blocks SSR until the response arrives. Even with client side navigation, 1kb file is transmitted with low latency and can't be noticeable. Try network throttling in devtools, I added custom modem preset (10 kbit/s) for such purposes, and it's still almost immediate with stackblitz worker, status: 0.0361328125 ms idle   status: 2.53515625 ms pending   status: 59.76220703125 ms success. Throttling shows a real delay on local copy

@EstusFlask Now I understand. Thank you for the explanation. Basically, I wanted to show a placeholder before the images load to prevent the main content from collapsing and the footer from touching the header. Once the images load, the content stretches, which looks odd. With SSR, it’s trickier since the content comes from the server. Using onload to check if each image is fully loaded might help (like Unsplash does), but I need to fill the space before the data arrives to avoid layout issues. Using v-if="status !== 'success'" on the skeleton doesn’t work because the response is too fast.

Makes sense. Then I guess you need to use useFetch+lazy without await,  and merge useFetch's status with image loading statuses for the resulting loading state. There should be high-level solutions to avoid messing with onload directly, like vueuse useImage. I'm unaware of anything specific to nuxt for this purpose, I didn't use @nuxt/image but it looks like a different cup of tea. Alternatively, if a skeleton isn't supposed to be shown more than once, you could make gallery comp to fully use suspense with "await useFetch" without lazy and render a skeleton as suspense fallback

@EstusFlask Thanks for the advice, I will try these approaches and reply/answer the question if one of solutions work.
